# Draw a line on a 3D model that conforms to its surface

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm building a tool for annotating three dimensional models using Three.js. I want users to be able to draw lines on a model that follow the contours of the surface exactly. For example, if you draw a line on a model of a person's face, and you place a point on either side of the nose, the line should go over the nose, not through it.

I can do this by drawing the line on the texture, but I want the line to be clickable, and that would require implementing hit detection myself. I'd prefer to do it as a line object in Three.js. Is there a simple way to find the faces between two points on the surface of a model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out to be easier than I thought: I converted the model to a graph of faces, where each face was a node, which was connected by edges to the other faces next to it. Then, it was a simple matter of finding the face that the user clicked on, and using a shortest-path algorithm (Dijkstra's, in my case) to find the faces between each node.

Comment: Could you share a picture, as it would be interesting to see the result?

Comment: would the code/demo be publicly available by any chance? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to come across this and remembered I also solved this problem in a similar way to Dave a while back. I made a minimal case with a demo here: https://github.com/foobarbecue/threejs-shortest-path